# What is the reason for split data in SQL to one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

There are many SQL UDFs that split string data such as `abc,def,ghi` mentioned here on StackOverFlow. However, most of them split this string into one column so the result of example above seems like this:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

What is the reason behind this logic? To split the several rows of strings into one column? How does one work with these data further? I can't imagine how this can be useful.

E.g. I have 10 rows of strings `abc,def,ghi`, split them by delimiter and put into one column. Then I end up with one column with 30 rows with one word per each.

```
1) Whats the logic?
2) What would be most likely the next steps? 
3) What if the data analyst needs to split the strings into column 
   so he ends up with 10 rows and 3 columns? 
   Should he choose different UDF in this case?
```

Comment: The process is called [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). What you gain? Performance, maintainability, [consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_%28database_systems%29), etc. What you need to do next? Create another table where you store those "words" and link them to the main-table via foreign-key.

Answer (score 1):

1. by normalizing your database this way, you make the data more atomic. Like this, you can easily add another value to the row of strings by inserting a new value into the table, use query functions to for example count how often one element of the list occurs in total etc.
2. the next steps to achieve what? Please elaborate in your question.
3. this makes no sense to me. Please elaborate in your question.